# React-Native: How to delete NSUserDefaults after updating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, nsuserdefaults

When I am updating from a native iOS application into my React-Native application, I am passing the user data from the native app from NSUserDefaults as initial props into the react-native application. After I handle the data into the react-native application, I will like somehow to be possible to remove the data.

Not removing the data will cause an error when a user is trying to reset his data that the NSUserDefaults data will be again taken in consideration.

What can be a solution for this? Can somehow  be modified from the JS land or just native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For removing NSUserDefault, the best way is to do it from the native part using

For one Key in particular

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

Or if you want to remove all keys

```
NSString *myApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:myApp];
```

If you don't know how to call native module from Javascript you can take a look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)